# Hidden div height (changing my advice)

Tags: jquery

Ok, I was going to answer someone's question here on SO about why their script wasn't working. They loaded content into a hidden div, then got the height so they could animate the wrapping div. But I always try to test the code I provide. So I made [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RdSzg/) to prove it to them.

So, umm, have I entered the twilight zone or am I dreaming right now? *pinches self* OUCH!

I tried that demo in Firefox, IE and Chrome and both methods return the same value. Firebug says zero! I rebooted my computer and I even changed the code a bit (removed the height function) and tried it with jQuery 1.3.2 and it still worked! I know hidden elements **USED** to return a zero value. Even this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery-1-4-2) is giving the advice I would have!

So I guess my question is... did I miss something or are we giving bad advice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the jQuery 1.4.2 and 1.3.2 source code, it actually performs this automatically when you call `width()` or `height()` on a hidden element. It sets the following attributes:

```
{ position: "absolute", visibility: "hidden", display:"block" }
```

Then it gets the width/height, and restores the old values of the attributes.

So there is no need to change the attributes yourself - jQuery will handle it for you.

**<Edit>**
This will allow you to get the dimensions of a hidden element. However, it won't work when the element is contained within another hidden element - you'll get a height of 0. In that case you'd need another solution, possibly like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery-1-4-2/2548882#2548882).
**</Edit>**

---

Here are the relevant bits of the source code from 1.4.2:

```
cssShow = { position: "absolute", visibility: "hidden", display:"block" },

//[undocumented jQuery.css function which is called by .height() and .width()]
css: function( elem, name, force, extra ) {
    if ( name === "width" || name === "height" ) {
        var val, props = cssShow, ....

        function getWH() {
            ... this function gets the actual width/height into the variable val
        }

        if ( elem.offsetWidth !== 0 ) {
            getWH();
        } else {
            jQuery.swap( elem, props, getWH );
        }

        return Math.max(0, Math.round(val));
    }
    return jQuery.curCSS( elem, name, force );
},

// A method for quickly swapping in/out CSS properties to get correct calculations
swap: function( elem, options, callback ) {
    var old = {};

    // Remember the old values, and insert the new ones
    for ( var name in options ) {
        old[ name ] = elem.style[ name ];
        elem.style[ name ] = options[ name ];
    }

    callback.call( elem );

    // Revert the old values
    for ( var name in options ) {
        elem.style[ name ] = old[ name ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice thanks! I guess I could have dug through the code, but I didn't think 1.3.2 already had implemented this code. I guess I need to update my advice :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, but the problem with appending the element to the end of the body is if the parent element has a size restriction, say a width setting, this won't get applied to the cloned element so the height value would be completely off. Oh well, something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with getting hidden element width, so I wrote this plugin call [jQuery Actual](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/get-hidden-elements-width-and-height-with-jquery/) to fix it. Instead of using

```
$('#some-element').height();
```

use

```
$('#some-element').actual('height');
```

will give you the right value for hidden element or element has a hidden parent.

You can also use

```
// get hidden element actaul width
$( '.hidden' ).actual( 'width' );

// get hidden element actaul innerWidth
$( '.hidden' ).actual( 'innerWidth' );

// get hidden element actaul outerWidth
$( '.hidden' ).actual( 'outerWidth' );

// get hidden element actaul height
$( '.hidden' ).actual( 'height' );

// get hidden element actaul innerHeight
$( '.hidden' ).actual( 'innerHeight' );

// get hidden element actaul outerHeight
$( '.hidden' ).actual( 'outerHeight' );
```

### Full documentation please see [here](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/get-hidden-elements-width-and-height-with-jquery/). There is also a demo include in the page.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the javascript's `scrollHeight` attribute.

```
$("#id_element").attr('scrollHeight')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hidden-element').get(0).height;
```

gives the height from DOM element, which is set also fro hidden elements