# Is there a "real height" in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Maybe it is a stupid question, but I'd like to know if there is a "power" function that get to me the real height of a div, counting also the "display:none;" height for each element on it.

Is it just a dream?

Comment: *"...counting also the "display:none;" height for each element on it."* `display: none` elements have no height. `visibility: hidden` ones do, but not `display: none` ones. *(Edit: And yet, according to [the question pointed out below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632120/jquery-height-width-and-displaynone), jQuery handles that)*

Comment: "display: none;" means it's not displayed hence there's no height or width. You will have to show all children inside the `<div>` and then check the height.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632120/jquery-height-width-and-displaynone

Comment: you can get the height of the existing elements in the dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that the height you're asking for is less "real" than than actual display height.  You have a few options:

1. Use `visibility: hidden` instead
2. Display all of the div's descendants, get the height, and hide them immediately
3. If number 2 doesn't work (elements are visible for too long possibly) clone the div, make it offscreen (`position: fixed; top: 100%` should do) and try #2 on *that* div.

http://jsfiddle.net/jrrdp/1/

Comment: True, working code for #2 is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jrrdp/) feel free to add into your post. :-)