# jquery height and width functions not working in internet explorer 9 when in a hidden iframe

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

When my code is embedded in an iframe that starts off as hidden in the parent page the jquery functions `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` return 0 regardless of what the css is set to. Then once the iframe is set to visible the resize event is not thrown, so there is no way to tell that the parent page has made it visible.

Here is an simple example of the problem http://www.mapdevelopers.com/test_large.html

Right now the only solution I have been able to come up with is to check on an interval to see if `$(window).width()` has a value over 0, and load the page accordingly once it does, but I assume there must be a better way to do this.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632120/jquery-height-width-and-displaynone

Comment: it appears that is what is happening in other browsers, but its not doing it on IE

Comment: I tested that page on IE, I clicked "Make Visible" button, it works fine. What's the problem?