# JQuery outerHeight() return none-zero on hidden (display:none) element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, outerheight

I think it should return 0 for display:none elements. but it doesn't, at least for 1.10.1

```
<div id="a" style="display:none">
    asdf
    asdfasdf<br>
    sadf
</div>

alert($('#a').outerHeight(true))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pUuAz/

Comment: I think it returns the height of an element irrespective of their display. `display:none` simply hides the element from view, the element is not collapsed.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632120/jquery-height-width-and-displaynone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery gives you the height of the element regardless to if it's displayed on the screen.

If you want it to ignore an hidden element use the following:

```
$('#a').is(':visible') ? $('#a').outerHeight(true) : 0;
```

Comment: This is just half-true. jQuery will give the height just if the element is directly hidden, but will return ```0``` in case the element set to ```display:none``` is an ancestor of the targeted element (see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKQvVN?editors=1111)

Answer (score 2):

digging into  $.css to $.style to  $.cssHooks to  $.cssHooks.height.get we see the culprit:

```
function ( elem, computed, extra ) {
            if ( computed ) {
                // certain elements can have dimension info if we invisibly show them
                // however, it must have a current display style that would benefit from this
                return elem.offsetWidth === 0 && rdisplayswap.test( jQuery.css( elem, "display" ) ) ?
                    jQuery.swap( elem, cssShow, function() {
                        return getWidthOrHeight( elem, name, extra );
                    }) :
                    getWidthOrHeight( elem, name, extra );
            }
}
```

it seems they swap the style, rip the value, then swap it back to display:none.