# Get Height of Newly Inserted Item in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to insert some HTML into the DOM. (`_articleTitleDivTemplate` is a string with HTML, and `_previewPane` is the element at the location I want to insert the item.)

```
var div = $(_articleTitleDivTemplate);
_previewPane.before(div);
alert(div.height());
```

Running in the debugger, I can see that `div` is what I expect. The inserted elements appear correctly on the page. Everything seems to work fine, except that the alert always displays 0.

Searching the web, it seems that this should have a height once I've called `before()`. How can I get the height of the newly inserted item?

*Note: At the time this code runs, the parent element is hidden, if that has any impact.*

Comment: Yes, I believe hidden elements (with display:none) have 0 dimentions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the element is hidden you are unable to get the height. Show it, get the height and then hide it.

```
var div = $(_articleTitleDivTemplate);
_previewPane.before(div);
_previewPane.show();
alert(div.height());
_previewPane.hide();
```

Comment: I thought jQuery did this internally when you asked for the size of hidden elements.

Comment: @r3mus His second sentence answers it.

Comment: Well, `_previewPane` is not the parent, but I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is addressed here:
[jQuery: Get height of hidden element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery)
...and here:
[jQuery: height()/width() and "display:none"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632120/jquery-height-width-and-displaynone)
...and here:
[jQuery - Get Width of Element when Not Visible (Display: None)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472303/jquery-get-width-of-element-when-not-visible-display-none)

Showing the element, grabbing the height, then hiding again may cause a flash on screen, so it's not ideal.

The most upvoted answer was to add some CSS properties to make jQuery think the element is visible, but in fact it is still hidden. Code samples over after the jump.