# jQuery width(); issues

Tags: jquery, width, padding

Long story short, I'm building a tool to hide tables on responsive websites when they won't fit. I've run into a weird bug that I hope someone can shed light on. When the table is hidden, jQuery suddenly decides to add 20px to its width. This is preventing me from doing calculations to re-show the table if the screen is made wide again. I will put the code below, but please view the jsFiddle to get a better idea of what's going on:

http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/mSAxJ/1/

```
// Check if table is too big for viewport. 
function tableChecker() {
    $(".rwd-table").each(function () {
        var wrapWidth1 = parseInt($(this).parent().width()),
            tableWidth = parseInt($(this).outerWidth());
        $('#debug').html('<font color="red">Wrapper Width:</font> ' + wrapWidth1 + 'px <font color="blue">Table Width:</font>' + tableWidth + 'px');
        if (wrapWidth1 < tableWidth) {
            var finaltableWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
            $(this).next('.viewtable').show();
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}


// Call on page load and page resize
tableChecker();
$(window).resize(function () {
    tableChecker();

});
```

I'm viewing this in Chrome 31, by the way.

Comment: I don't see a `else` statement checking if `wrapWidth1 >= tableWidth`. Could that help?

Comment: The function should just STOP after the initial if statement, but it doesn't due to those extra pixels jQuery is calculating on the hidden table.

Comment: FYI- this is a reduced test case here. My full code can be seen here if it helps in any way: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/fg3Eq/7/

Comment: How about removing the horizontal padding on `.viewtable` ?

Comment: small bit of debugging: if you remove the padding on html,body, it goes away.

Comment: Daniel - Good thought, but thats not it.
Kevin- Yes, I found the padding added is related to the parents' padding, whether that is the body or another div. I want to be able to use this where ever, without worrying about the parents' padding though.

Comment: added in the JS:   else if (wrapWidth1 > tableWidth){
            $(this).show();
        } and removed the padding on the body that seems to work

Comment: I am aware that removing the body padding does the trick. The problem is that this will be used in situations where there IS padding around it. I can't understand how the body padding is affecting the calculated width of the table, only after it is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after messing with this forever, I've decided it is a bug that happens when you try measuring a width on a hidden object. My work-around is to leave the object visible, and put it in a container with height:0, and overflow:hidden. This provides the correct width.

Comment: Not a bug. Expected behavior. Another common approach is `position: absolute; left: -999em;`.

Answer (score 0):

Think I have something for you, it looks like when ever an element has `display: none;` that query does some extra stuff in the background that allows it to "guess" a height/width

related: [jQuery: height()/width() and "display:none"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632120/jquery-height-width-and-displaynone)

Unless an element has specific sizes hide() will set its width/height to auto and then it has to guess at those sizes.

Run this fiddle and check out the chrome dev tools and console
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Culyx/aN6x7/2/

CSS:

```
#one{
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
#two{
    background-color: blue;
}
#clickMe{
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

JS:

```
console.log($("#one").height());
console.log($("#one").width());

console.log($("#two").height());
console.log($("#two").width());

$("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $("#one").hide();
    $("#two").hide();

    console.log("Now they're hidden");
    console.log($("#one").height());
    console.log($("#one").width());

    console.log($("#two").height());
    console.log($("#two").width());
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="one">Hello</div>
<div id="two">Hello</div>

<div id="clickMe">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, I had assumed that a hidden object would get a width of NaN. I'm curious how it 'guesses' and if there's any way to help it guess more correctly.

Comment: Not sure how it does it now but the other subject did touch on the process a bit, I'd wager it still uses the swap method and tries to judge based on how the element would fit.