# !important and display:none and .height() weirdness

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I discovered something weird yesterday when working with a piece of JS code. I had a `div` that was hidden (`display:none`), and I was using the height of it in some calculations in JS. This was all working fine, until I added my "hidden" class (which has `display:none !important`).

Suddenly the height was always `0`. There were no other changes than `!important` on the display.

After some digging I've narrowed the problem down to something I find rather weird:

```css
#b { display:none; }            /* reported height is 36 */
#c { display:none !important; } /* reported height is 0  */
```

I've created a very basic [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kZ3ee/3/) to isolate this. It also uses vanilla JS to get height, which seems to work just fine / as expected.

It seems like jQuery incorrectly reports height on invisible DIVs, and that `!important` behaves correctly.

Is this a bug in jQuery?

Comment: Most likely your `display: none;` without `!important` gets overruled.
Display none should indeed return 0

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: height()/width() and "display:none"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632120/jquery-height-width-and-displaynone)

Comment: @user3008011 No, see the fiddle.

Comment: @DAC84 That does not cover the !important usage

Comment: If you manually set a height, it reports it. http://jsfiddle.net/kZ3ee/6/

Comment: True, but it explains what is happening and worth linking to to save largely duplicating that answer. If you understand that !important overrides inline styles then you have the answer with that question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I dont think this is a bug in jQuery, jQuery sets `display` to `block` for a fraction of a second to calculate `height`, when you set `!important` even that is ovverriden, thats all.

I guess we need some more explanation

There is basically no way to get the `height` of an element from DOM if it doesn't have any height. So when `display` is `none`, the `height` is nonexistent or `zero`.

In jQuery if `display` is `none`, we can just set `display` to `block` for a fraction of a second to get the `height`, during this `inline` style is altered as usually done by jQuery.

```
<div id="something" style="display:block">/div>
```

And then `height` is taken, but at this time if you have set `display:none!important` in css this inline style wont work, and `height` calculated becomes `zero`.

In my personal opinion its always better not to use !important as it makes your code/presentation hard to read. Css usually has multitude of ways to override styles.

If you still want to proceed, an inline `!important` might override your style, and calculate the height by yourself using the jQuery show for a second technique, or just override the jQuery function to calculate height :)

Comment: Why does `$('#c')` have a height of 0 then?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly because `!important` can override even inline styles, which we usually consider that is not overriden by anything.

Comment: Ill better explain in the answer

Comment: @sabithpocker I think you are spot on. Thanks!