# Setting element heights using jQuery giving improper height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of elements (cards I'm calling them) which are each 33% width in order to fill the page.  Inside them is a header and a detail and I want to show the detail of all of them from the click of a checkbox.  The length of the detail is variable between all the cards so when the user clicks to show the details I attempt to get the height of each card's detail, set them all the same, and then show the details on them all.

I set the heights correctly but once `slideDown()` is called on them they are given a height that is greater than what I set.  I was finally able to figure out that it has something to do with `data-set-label` and `data-set-data` being `inline-block` and having a width of 50%.  If I remove that, `slideDown()` shows the proper height.  It's almost as if `slideDown()` is not taking into consideration that the inline block elements are on the same line, but that doesn't seem right...

What's going wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ShowDetailsCheckBox").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      setContentDataHeights();
      $(".cards-card-detail").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(".cards-card-detail").slideUp();
    }
  });
});

function setContentDataHeights() {
  var maxContentDataHeight = 0;

  $(".cards-card-detail").each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > maxContentDataHeight)
      maxContentDataHeight = $(this).height();
  });

  if (maxContentDataHeight > 0) {
    $(".cards-card-detail").each(function() {
      //$(this).css("height", maxContentDataHeight.toString() + "px");
      $(this).height(maxContentDataHeight);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cards {
  font-size: 0;
}

.cards-card {
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cards-card:nth-child(2n) {
  width: 34%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.cards-card-header {
  height: 100px;
}

.cards-card-detail {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  display: none;
}

.data-set-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}

.data-set-label {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.data-set-data {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="ShowDetailsCheckBox" />Show details
<div class="cards">
  <div class="cards-card">
    <div class="cards-card-header">
      Here is some header information
    </div>
    <div class="cards-card-detail">
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards-card">
    <div class="cards-card-header">
      Here is some header information
    </div>
    <div class="cards-card-detail">
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards-card">
    <div class="cards-card-header">
      Here is some header information
    </div>
    <div class="cards-card-detail">
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tn86cs2k/8/)

Comment: Flexbox is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty funky.

**A Theory:**

When `.cards-card-detail` elements have `display:none`, their widths are undefined. The `.data-set-label` elements have `width:50%` but, with their parents' widths undefined, their widths get calculated in a strange way which causes inner text to wrap and heights to get thrown off.

**Some Tests:**

In the test below, the width of `.data-set-label` is computed as "50 pixels", even though it's defined as "50%". But when `.cards-card-detail` is `display:block`, a more accurate width is returned.

```js
$(function() {
  console.log("display:none - " + $('.data-set-label').width());
  $('.cards-card-detail').show()
  console.log("display:block - " + $('.data-set-label').width());
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cards {
  font-size: 0;
}

.cards-card {
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cards-card:nth-child(2n) {
  width: 34%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.cards-card-header {
  height: 100px;
}

.cards-card-detail {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  display: none;
}

.data-set-wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
}

.data-set-label {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.data-set-data {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cards">
  <div class="cards-card">
    <div class="cards-card-header">
      Here is some header information
    </div>
    <div class="cards-card-detail">
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Setting the width of `.data-set-label` explicitly to "50px" makes the text wrap and increases the height of `.cards-card-detail`, seemingly to the same "wrong" height as in your example (coincidence?).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cards {
  font-size: 0;
}

.cards-card {
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cards-card:nth-child(2n) {
  width: 34%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.cards-card-header {
  height: 100px;
}

.cards-card-detail {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.data-set-wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
}

.data-set-label {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.data-set-data {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cards">
  <div class="cards-card">
    <div class="cards-card-header">
      Here is some header information
    </div>
    <div class="cards-card-detail">
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**A Solution:**

I had some success by defining the width of `.cards-card-detail` at "100%" in the hopes that the childrens' "50%" width would then be set correctly.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#ShowDetailsCheckBox").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      setContentDataHeights();
      $(".cards-card-detail").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(".cards-card-detail").slideUp();
    }
  });

});

function setContentDataHeights() {

  var maxContentDataHeight = 0;

  $(".cards-card-detail").each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > maxContentDataHeight)
      maxContentDataHeight = $(this).height();
  });

  if (maxContentDataHeight > 0) {
    $(".cards-card-detail").height(maxContentDataHeight);
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cards {
  font-size: 0;
}

.cards-card {
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cards-card:nth-child(2n) {
  width: 34%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.cards-card-header {
  height: 100px;
}

.cards-card-detail {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.data-set-wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
}

.data-set-label {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.data-set-data {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="ShowDetailsCheckBox" />Show details
<div class="cards">
  <div class="cards-card">
    <div class="cards-card-header">
      Here is some header information
    </div>
    <div class="cards-card-detail">
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards-card">
    <div class="cards-card-header">
      Here is some header information
    </div>
    <div class="cards-card-detail">
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards-card">
    <div class="cards-card-header">
      Here is some header information
    </div>
    <div class="cards-card-detail">
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm curious about other explanations.

---

**EDIT:**

I see what you mean: the solution above doesn't work consistently.
Here's a alternative technique:

Set `.cards` to `opacity:0` until the heights of `.card-card-detail` are set. Then reveal the cards.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setContentDataHeights();
  $('.cards-card-detail').hide();
  $('.cards').addClass('show');

  $("#ShowDetailsCheckBox").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(".cards-card-detail").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(".cards-card-detail").slideUp();
    }
  });
});

function setContentDataHeights() {
  var maxContentDataHeight = 0;

  $(".cards-card-detail").each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > maxContentDataHeight)
      maxContentDataHeight = $(this).height();
  });

  if (maxContentDataHeight > 0) {
    $(".cards-card-detail").height(maxContentDataHeight);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cards {
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}

.cards.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cards-card {
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cards-card:nth-child(2n) {
  width: 34%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.cards-card-header {
  height: 100px;
}

.cards-card-detail {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.data-set-wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
}

.data-set-label {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.data-set-data {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="ShowDetailsCheckBox" />Show details
<div class="cards">
  <div class="cards-card">
    <div class="cards-card-header">
      Here is some header information
    </div>
    <div class="cards-card-detail">
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">label label label label label label </label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards-card">
    <div class="cards-card-header">
      Here is some header information
    </div>
    <div class="cards-card-detail">
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">label label label label label label label label label label </label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards-card">
    <div class="cards-card-header">
      Here is some header information
    </div>
    <div class="cards-card-detail">
      <div class="data-set-wrapper">
        <label class="data-set-label">Label</label>
        <div class="data-set-data">
          some data
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent idea with the width 100%...I hadn't thought of that.  However, it's not quite working.  Take a look at this [link]https://jsfiddle.net/tn86cs2k/29/.  If the data runs onto more than 1 line the height gets calculated incorrectly and the content extends outside the detail.  Also, not sure if this is worth pointing out, but you had mentioned the display: none width being 50?  If I change the width of the label to 55%, just for grins, jquery calculates a width of 55, so, can we really trust that it's width is 50 when display is none?

Comment: This some help from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632120/jquery-height-width-and-displaynone I added position: relative to cards-card and that seems to nearly fix the content stretching outside the detail.  I'm still not getting perfect heights on things yet though.