# How can I get the height of an element which has got a parent element that has display: none?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I get the height of an element which has got a parent element that has `display: none`?

An example here: [**jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/luksak/Gts6A/65/)

Thanks

Lukas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Temporarily `show()`ing an element to retrieve a child's height seems to work OK.

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="target" style="display:none;">
    <!-- Add a background color to see if it's noticeable -->
    <div style="height:123px; background:#000;"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```js
// Show the hidden parent of the element we want the height of
$("#target").show(0, function(){
    // Find and grab the height of the element we want
    the_height = $(this).find("div").height();
// Hide parent and display child's height after it
}).hide().after(the_height);
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Gts6A/72](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/Gts6A/72/)**

Comment: +1 for a nice trick...but showing and hiding a div will cause a blink effect.

Comment: @Vivek: Doesn't seem to for me.

Comment: This can definitely cause a browser to blink on an older pc. This is because it forces a complete re-layout twice in a row. I'd recommend thoroughly testing this solution before relying on it.

Comment: `the_height` is an implicit global variable. Implicit globals should be avoided, declare it as a local variable rather.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this or you can use the hack from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery-1-4-2).

```
$("#target").parent().show();
var h = $("#target").height();
$("#target").parent().hide();
alert(h);
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5y8H/).

Answer (score 1):

`it's very difficult(in other word you can't)` to get the height of hidden element...because `dom doesn't consider hidden elements while rendering the page`.

Answer (score 1):

Hidden elements have an undefined width and height, so it's not possible to get em.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit klunky but you have to have an object rendered before it can be measured.

```
var $target = $("#target");

$target[0].parentNode.runtimeStyle.display = "block";
var height = $target.height();
$target[0].parentNode.runtimeStyle.display = "none";
alert(height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you should display the div or it is impossible to get the height of the hidden elements. I would say, use .show() to show the div, get the height and then use .hide() to hide it again..