# jQuery outerHeight for hidden element

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem with getting the outer height of a list item - similar to the below post:
[jQuery: Get height of hidden element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery-1-4-2)

Here is my code:

```
function tabload() {
    $('.tab li:first-child').addClass('selected');

    $(".tab ul").css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'visibility': 'hidden', 'display': 'block'});

    var h = $(".tab ul").outerHeight(true);

    $(".tab ul").css("height", h);

    $(".tab ul").css({'position': 'relative', 'visibility': 'visible', 'display': 'none' });
};
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have blogged about this issue before since there are a few other similar questions here on stackoverflow.  Take a look at the code in this [blog post](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/getting-the-width-of-a-hidden-element-with-jquery-using-width/)

I initially developed it just for the width method, but based on comments the code has evolved to include inner/outer dimensions.

Comment: I did see this post actually but wasn't able to solve it myself. Not sure if it matters but i am using asp.net with razor mvc. would it help if i added my css and html? Ive already started to recode this, but surely there is a solution!

Comment: Being able to see your HTML and CSS would help recreating the issue.  I could then play around with and see what I can find.

Comment: Here is the HTML/CSS - Ive removed some code as its in asp.net mvc razor.

CSS
    ul.tab {margin-top:10px; clear:both; position:relative;} ul.tab li {float:left; background:none;}
    ul.tab ul {display:none; position:absolute}
    ul.tab li.selected ul {display:block; left:0;}
    ul.tab li a {display:block;}
    ul.lineup li {float:left; height:auto !important;}

HTML
    <ul class="tab">
        <li>
            <ul class="lineup">
            
                <li>Name</li>

            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

Comment: What value are you getting for the height and what value are you expecting?

Comment: I am getting 0 but expecting the height to be whatever is loaded in the <li> - this depends on what comes back from the server for that particular <li>

Comment: There must be something else affecting it that I don't have.  I set up an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/YReWs/ and I am getting a non-zero value for h inside of tabload.

Answer (score 0):

You may not get the height/widith of hidden(display:none;) elements in all the browsers. Try to show the element and hide it after you get the height.

```
function tabload() {
    $('.tab li:first-child').addClass('selected');

    $(".tab ul").show();

    var h = $(".tab ul").outerHeight(true);

    $(".tab ul").css("height", h);

    $(".tab ul").css({'position': 'relative', 'visibility': 'visible', 'display': 'none' });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using display: none you may consider to use position absolute with some huge margin. eg position:absolute;left:-999999px; instead.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're confusing `visibility` and `display`. `visibility` shows the space for the element on the page, but doesn't actually render it. `display: none` won't show the element or the space it fills.

So when you set

```
$(".tab ul").css({'position': 'relative', 'visibility': 'visible', 'display': 'none' });
```

You're actually completely hiding the element

Comment: He's not confused. If he didn't set the visibility property back to `visible` it wouldn't appear when he used `show()`. Look at all his code bro.

Comment: I was looking at his code bro, and my point was more that he shouldn't be using `visibility` at all.

Comment: If it is hidden via `display:none` it takes up no space on the DOM so the only way to get the height is to set it to `display:block`. He probably didn't want the content to be visible on the screen so he kept it invisible with `visibility:hidden`, grabbed the height, and then reset all his css.

Comment: Thats right @AlienWebguy - It also stops the page flickering when it shows and hides the content