# Forcing Kendo UI Chart to use full width of Bootstrap tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-chart, bootstrap-tabs

I have a page where I have 3 Kendo UI graphs, each in a separate tab. I want all graphs to use the full width available, but only the first one does so.

I know I can specify a width for the chart, but I don't want to / cannot specify this upfront (responsiveness and all). I've tried playing around with the width of the divs containing the charts. I've also tried setting the `col-lg-12` class on these divs. Nothing seems to work.

This is my html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="#chart1" data-toggle="tab">Chart 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#chart2" data-toggle="tab">Chart 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#chart3" data-toggle="tab">Chart 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="chart1">
        <div id="chart1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="chart2">
        <div id="chart2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="chart3">
        <div id="chart3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A working example can be found in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/petermorlion/wgzg0htt/1/).

Comment: Rienus fix works in your jsFiddle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206631/why-are-bootstrap-tabs-displaying-tab-pane-divs-with-incorrect-widths-when-using . Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Your tab-pane ID and chart div ID should not be the same.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="chart1tab">
    <div id="chart1"></div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="chart2tab">
    <div id="chart2"></div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="chart3tab">
    <div id="chart3"></div>
</div>
```

Kendo provides a resize method that automatically adjusts the chart widths as the page/container is resized. You could call this when the window is resized and when a tab is shown:

```
$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function () {        
    kendo.resize($("body"));
});

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    kendo.resize($("body"));
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/wgzg0htt/5/)**

If you still have issues with the initial size, you could create the charts the first time the corresponding tab is shown.