# Highcharts are squished in html tabs

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've three tabs in http://quantprice.com/demo.html that have charts. My issues are:

- Why are the charts squished to the left quarter in the **Smokey** tab (and the following 3 tabs)? They behave as expected as soon as I press the "Alt" key.
- Why are there 2 menu icons on the top right corner of the charts in the  **Sparkling** tab but only 1 in the **Smokey** tab chart?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you add the configurations for all 3 charts?

Comment: Isn't that part of the demo.html page?

Comment: 1) Charts should be expaned to whole tab or Im wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. Charts to cover the whole tab.

Comment: Try to set width as 100% on chart container. if not, you can use solution from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206631/why-are-bootstrap-tabs-displaying-tab-pane-divs-with-incorrect-widths-when-using) thread

Comment: Sounded complicated so I just switched to divisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) You load exporting.js module two times, remove one of them to leave single exporting icon

Comment: Yes, this fixed the exporting icon duplication issue.

Comment: issue 1 of squished charts is still happening.