# highcharts graphs in bootstrap tabs are not displaying properly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, tabs

I have two tabs, tab 1 and tab 2, when the page is initially loaded, the graph in the first tab is loaded at the same time, which is fitting right in `col-md-6`, now, when I click tab 2, the graph in that tab gets collapsed to almost half of the first one, I want it to also fit in the `col-md-6` right and fine, Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Please, have a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bilalahmed7827/r9dt5j4n/)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206631/why-are-bootstrap-tabs-displaying-tab-pane-divs-with-incorrect-widths-when-using). It's caused by width of hidden elements, where browser doesn't calculate it.

Comment: @PawełFus I read ryenus's answer, but the issue still remains when I resize the browser window.

Comment: Try also my solutions, for example: `render chart at the beginning, but after tab click call chart.reflow()`.

Comment: @PawełFus Can you please try editing my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bilalahmed7827/r9dt5j4n/) , I've tried it myself but no gain, may be I'm doing it wrong, I just added this line `$('#graph-container-gray').highcharts().reflow()` on the tab 2 click event, isn't it?

Comment: See answer by Udhay Titus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this jquery tab select function, it will solve your problem.

[here is modified fiddle click here](https://jsfiddle.net/r9dt5j4n/6/)

```
 jQuery(document).on( 'shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) { // on tab selection event
    jQuery( "#graph-container-gray, #graph-container-red" ).each(function() {
        var chart = jQuery(this).highcharts(); // target the chart itself
        chart.reflow() // reflow that chart
    });
})
```

Comment: This is Perfect, Thank you soo much.. +1000 :)

Answer (score 0):

Take A Look At This Fiddle 
[Click To View](https://jsfiddle.net/r9dt5j4n/17/)

```
<div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="graph-container-gray" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                </div>

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="2">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="graph-container-red" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```