# Highcharts (PieChart) - chart width reduced on drawing second time

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, charts, highcharts

First of all thanks to HighCharts.. Well, I am building a pie chart using HighCharts in jQuery Mobile.

I am displaying few pie charts (max 6 charts) which is created dynamically in an Ajax success callback depending on the response data. The Ajax is called initially in ***document.ready()*** and also on a button click.

During the creation of the pie charts from ***document.ready()***, all charts displays horizontally centered to the screen, which is an expected result. But next time when it creates from the button click, it moves little left, ie, its width is reduced than it was displayed on document.ready().

I am creating each container `<div id="container-x"></div>` for the pie charts dynamically.
Here is the sample code I used to create the chart. The **dataArray** is the data set used to plot the pie chart.

```
$('#container' + i).highcharts({
 chart: {
     plotBackgroundColor: null,
     plotBorderWidth: null,
     plotShadow: false,
     type: 'pie',
     marginBottom: 150,
     marginLeft: 20
 },
 title: {
     text: ''
 },
 tooltip: {
     pointFormat: '<b>{point.y:.0f}</b>'
 },
 plotOptions: {
     pie: {
         allowPointSelect: true,
         cursor: 'pointer',
         showInLegend: true,
         dataLabels: {
             enabled: true,
             useHTML: true,
             formatter: function () {
                 return Math.round(this.percentage * 100) / 100 + '%';
             },
             style: {
                 fontWeight: 'bold',
                 color: 'black'
             }
         }
     }
 },
 legend: {
     layout: 'vertical',
     align: 'left',
     verticalAlign: 'bottom',
     useHTML: true,
     maxHeight: 135,
     itemMarginTop: 2,
     itemMarginBottom: 2,
     labelFormatter: function () {
         var words = this.name.split(/[\s]+/);
         var numWordsPerLine = 4;
         var str = [];
         for (var word in words) {
             if (word > 0 && word % numWordsPerLine == 0) {
                 str.push('<br>');
             }
             str.push(words[word]);
         }
         return (str.slice(0, str.length - 2)).join(' ');
     },
     navigation: {
         activeColor: '#3E576F',
         animation: true,
         arrowSize: 12,
         inactiveColor: '#CCC',
         useHTML: true,
         style: {
             fontWeight: 'bold',
             color: '#333',
             fontSize: '12px'
         }
     }
 },
 series: [{
     name: 'Brands',
     colorByPoint: true,
     data: dataArray
 }]
});
```

Attaching the two screens below

**1.** Expected - initially loaded pie chart
[image: Expected and initially loaded pie chart]

**2.** Width reduced - loaded on button click
[image: Width reduced]

Btw, I have two div's, one with few filters and a submit button and other one is the chart that is displayed. Also am hiding the div that displays chart when I need to display a filter based chart and displays on the ajax response.

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/sadiqmc/6grd8mrL/8/)

Thank in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding size to your pie? It may help you with your issue: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński: Let me try that...

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński: Its still the same.. :(

Comment: Could you show live example of this issue? Like jsFiddle?

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I can't find the issue in jsFiddle. :(  The jsFiddle has a basic functionality am trying to achieve in the app.  here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sadiqmc/6grd8mrL/7/)

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński: Found the reason for the issue... Try loading the chart after hiding the chart div, you can find the issue at that time.. But when you load the chart without hiding, the chart displays perfectly.  Please find the updated jsFiddle code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sadiqmc/6grd8mrL/8/)

Comment: Hi emcees, thanks for all the information, they are really helpful. Problems with hiding divs are really common, you can find topic connected with this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206631/why-are-bootstrap-tabs-displaying-tab-pane-divs-with-incorrect-widths-when-using

Comment: Thanx GrzegorzBlachliński for supporting to find the reason behind this issue.. So its a known issue with Highcharts

Comment: I am not sure if we can call it really an issue with Highcharts or with understanding of hidden div in browsers. You may try to manually set size of your chart, using chart.width and chart.height - maybe it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with hiding of the `<div>`. I was hiding the div with jQuery's `hide()` function

Please find a similar answer for [Why are Bootstrap tabs displaying tab-pane divs with incorrect widths when using highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17215031/2906742)