# highcharts not responsive and overlapping on first view

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Im having a small issue with my highcharts.

Oddly when i first view the page, the donut chart overlaps with my line chart but when i resize the window or open firebug it comes to its original position.

When i check the firebug console there are no errors related jquery or javascript.

also i have set the container width to `100%` but none of the charts are becoming responsive...

Demo : http://vidznet.com/debug/

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: try to add
#container_donut{
display:inline-block;
}
And check its working or not ?

Comment: @Ankitvadariya i added but still doesnt work

Comment: Please try to add class col-md-12 to same id container_donut

Comment: @Ankitvadariya added but still doesnt work..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Bootstrap tabs displaying tab-pane divs with incorrect widths when using highcharts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206631/why-are-bootstrap-tabs-displaying-tab-pane-divs-with-incorrect-widths-when-using)