# highcharts layout position broken until page is reszied

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

im having a strange problem with my web page which uses jquery, jquery mobile, bootstrap and high charts.

There are 2 highcharts on 2 separate blocks. Initially when i visit the page they layout of the charts looks messed up, but when i resize the window and maximize it, it works fine.

On the highchart containers i have set the width to 100% to make it responsive. But when i remove the width from the div it works fine but i lose the responsiveness

Demo http://vidznet.com/debug/

can someone please tell me what might be causing it?

Comment: I think this has something to do with the `width` defined inline as 1600px; Make it a percentage... `<svg version="1.1" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1600" height="400">`

Comment: @LiveEn in div with `class="highcharts-container" id="highcharts-0"`, where inline style is added. I think this is problem

Comment: This question has been answered many times on SO - basically highcharts is not able to calculate correctly the container's width when the div is not visible - you can use chart.reflow() after the chart is loaded - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=highcharts+bootstrap+width
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206631/why-are-bootstrap-tabs-displaying-tab-pane-divs-with-incorrect-widths-when-using