# Google charts inside bootstrap tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to apply ryenus solution ([Why are Bootstrap tabs displaying tab-pane divs with incorrect widths when using highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206631/why-are-bootstrap-tabs-displaying-tab-pane-divs-with-incorrect-widths-when-using)) for google charts and twitter bootstrap tabs but i have a problem, maybe because i have different version of bootstrap,i am not sure. My version of bootstrap is 3.3.7 .

On my bootstrap.css file i found this lines:

```css
.tab-content > .tab-pane {
  display: none;
}
.tab-content > .active {
  display: block;
}
```

Also i applied the patch after the bootstrap.css but i have a bug like in picture below,can someone help me? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot searching i tried this and i solve my issue.

```js
$("a[href='#C']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['timeline'],
        callback: drawChartC
    });
});
```