# Invalid width on creating hidden highchart

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

On the site there are several pie charts. All diagrams are created immediately after the page loads. At the moment of creation, part of the diagrams is hidden (the parent layer display: none)
Visible charts are set correctly, hidden charts have parameter is incorrect width.

The layer of the diagram

```
<div id="DGramm" style="width: 100%;"> </ div>
```

The result - the diagram created on the entire width of the page, but no of the width of the parent layer. How to do the right, to take the width of the hidden layer?

At this point, all that came up - to create a chart after the first showing of the hidden layer.

Comment: Answer by @Sridhar R is correct, check [FAQ](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#jquery-ui-tab) also.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the window.resize event to update the Chart size. Add this script to your page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383350/highstocks-graph-width-not-correctly-rendered). Thanks, [david](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529204/david).