# Jquery getting a hidden element's height

Tags: jquery, hidden

I was trying to get a list of element's height value but it was returning 0.
I've done some research and saw that in order get  element's height, that element must be visible.
But I want to check its height when it's hidden. If its height is bigger than some value use some functions then make it visible. Is there any way to do this?

I mean:

1. Check hidden element's height.
2. If it has OK value make it visible.
3. If it doesn't have required value do some functions.
4. Make it visible.

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery-1-4-2

Comment: it works with hidden elements - http://jsfiddle.net/xgbEv/

Comment: @ken redler: that is the best solution i found about this. i just had to use .appendTo('body') because it didn't work with .show()

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can `show` the element get the height and then hide it, visually you will not see any difference.

```
var height = $('elementSelector').show().height();
$('elementSelector').hide();
if(height != <<HeightToCompare>>){
    //Code here
}
//Finally make it visible
$('elementSelector').show();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PdEbM/)**

Comment: I tought showing an element then hiding it will cause some visual issue but i test it now. Yes it's doesnt make any problem. Thanks for help.

Comment: But, if you look at my answer, you'll see you don't need to do that.

Comment: @AlienWebguy - IE6 gives 0 if the element is hidden.

Comment: This looks like it works..I too thought it would flicker but it doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to clone the object, position the clone far outside the viewport, make it visible, measure the clone, then destroy it.

So you have:

```
<div id="maybe" style="display: none;">
  Something
</div>
```

Since you're using jQuery, you'd do something like this:

```
$('#maybe')
  .clone()
  .attr('id','maybe_clone') // prevent id collision
  .css({                    // position far outside viewport
    'position': 'absolute',
    'left': '-1000px'
  });

if( $('#maybe_clone').show().height() > 200 ) {
  $('#maybe').show();
}

$('#maybe_clone').remove();       // housekeeping
```

Comment: +1, that or temporarily position absolutely and move the element itself. Since the element is hidden to begin with, it will not disturb the markup.

Comment: If `display:none` is applied to a parent element, this won't work. A fix would be injecting the clone outside it's original parent: `.clone().appendTo('body')`.

Comment: thanks to give me clue to calculate hidden div height

Answer (score 0):

Position the object so it is visible to the browser, but not the user:
[jQuery: Get height of hidden element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery-1-4-2)