# jQuery dialog position depending on content

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

I am loading jQuery dialogs that contain tabs inside. The tabs vary in height but the position is calculated on the first tab that is loaded. Is it possible to position the dialog according the the biggest tab inside?

Comment: Try setting the dialog `height` option to the height of the highest tab.  You try doing this during the dialog `create` or `open` events.

Comment: So when the dialog is created or opened, I get the height of the highest tab and then pass it as a parameter right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Although I haven't tried it out myself yet.

Comment: Did not manage to get it to work. I think the height is not able to be calculated since the big tab would be hidden on dialog open

Comment: Just tested and you are correct. Try getting the height using this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery