# HTML5/CSS3 make a square div, width is 100%, need height equals width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using HTML5 and CSS3 to make a layout.

I need tiles on the page, which is a square div element. the tile is inside a bootstrap column, I need the width to be automatically match the column width, but I found it difficult to let the height = width, because width is a percentage value: 100%.

HTML:

```
...
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="tile tile-square tile-auto">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
...
```

CSS:

```
.tile-square{
    width: 100%;
    height: how to do this?
}
```

I am OK with jQuery/js solution, but I prefer using CSS3 to solve this alone. there is a "calc()" statement in CSS3, but I do not know if it can achive this functionality.

Comment: check these [link1](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://siebennull.com/equal_width_height.html

Answer (score 2):

With pure CSS2.1, you can make a box preserve a 1:1 ratio by setting `padding-top: 100%` (since vertical paddings are calculated from the container width, not height). The comments to your question provide some links with examples.

Answer (score 2):

Done with jQuery

```
var x = $('.element').width();
$('.element').css(
    {'height': x + 'px'}
);
```

Demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamcem/SJtrd/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot do this with just CSS3. CSS simply does styling. You can achieve this with JQuery/JS though:

```
var width = $('div.tile-square').width();
$('div.tile-square').height(width + 'px');
```

Or you can do this (not as preferred):

```
$('div.tile-square').css('height', $('div.tile-square').css('width'));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7k8pp/3/

Comment: in my opinion he should use .height() and .width() instead of .ccs('height') and .css('width')

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe the only difference between those functions is one returns the value in `px` and one returns an actual number (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279555/csswidth-and-cssheight-vs-width-and-height)). For this situation, it does not really matter.

Comment: I know the difference between them. In my opinion correct practice is to store width in a different variable and then use it as height. Your method produced many bugs for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but still relevant. It's been mentioned that this can be achieved using pure CSS although without a comprehensive example.

To preserve the aspect ratio of any element, we can use `padding-top` (which is based on the width of the element). So if we set the width of an element to be `25%` for example, setting the `padding-top` property to `25%` will force the element to become a square.

Have a look at the example below:

```css
.tile {  
  background: #369; float: left;
  width: 23%;
  margin: 1%;
  position: relative;
}
.tile-square {
  padding-top: 23%; /* 23% (.tile width) - 2% (top and bottom margin) */
  height: 0;
}
.tile__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
body {margin: 1%;}
```

```html
<div class="tile tile-square tile-auto">
  <div class="tile__content">Tile 1</div>
</div>
<div class="tile tile-square tile-auto">
  <div class="tile__content">Tile 2</div>
</div>
<div class="tile tile-square tile-auto">
  <div class="tile__content">Tile 3</div>
</div>
<div class="tile tile-square tile-auto">
  <div class="tile__content">Tile 4</div>
</div>
```

## There is an issue with this method...

Because we have used padding to force the height of the element to be the same as the width, if we then add content to `.tile`, the content added will seemingly appear at the bottom and the element will no longer be a square.
To overcome this, we set the `.tile` element to be positioned `relative` and then add a second element (`.tile__content`) inside. We then position `.tile__content` absolutely so it sits over the area the padding occupies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the pure css method, but in jquery you can use `$( document ).width();`. It will return width and you can set it as height.

`$( document ).width();` will return value in `px`.