# real height of element that is hidden withing another element

Tags: jquery, height, overflow, hidden

I've got a problem, but it only appears at firefox. 
When I'm trying to get element's height it returns only the visible part of element (in firefox, in rest of the browsers it returns whole element height).

The structure is following:

```
<ul class="slider">
   <li><div>//content</div></li>
   <li><div>//content</div></li>
   <li><div>//content</div></li>
   ...
</ul>
```

I'm using caroufredsel script for carousel. I need to get the height of highest element to set the height of the whole carousel, cause when i'm trying to use the option height:"auto" it still doesn't work.

So I'm asking - how to get the real height of element which is partially hidden because of overflow property?

Comment: Can we see your javascript code to get the height of elements ?

Comment: ok, so to clarify more, first I'm running over each li element in the list using `$('ul.slider li').each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
   maxHeight = $(this).height();
  }  
  if (0 == --count) initializeSlider();
 });` and then i start the slider with height: maxHeight option. Also when I checked the inspector in firefox height of elements is different than that which has been return using .height().

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `outerHeight` instead of `height` or look at this - http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/get-hidden-elements-width-and-height-with-jquery/ - it allows to use such constructions: `$( '.hidden' ).actual( 'width' );`

Comment: I had changed my answer. Look again, please.

Comment: also tried that library, still returns only the visible part of the element.. why that only happens with firefox?

Comment: Just found the same question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery

Comment: it's not same, cause my element isn't hidden, it's overflow is set to hidden only, the element is visible and display is set to block

Comment: Could you make jsfiddle example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3pZW3/1/ but as I can see the problem does not appear here, it must be something with container then..

Comment: okay, I've already figured it out, it was because the script that prevents content flickering...