# How's jquery able to get the height of a hidden div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please look at the following link.

http://jsfiddle.net/YJMrE/

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="test1">test 1</div>
    <div id="test2">test 2</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").hide();
    alert($("#test").height());
    alert(document.getElementById("test").getBoundingClientRect().height);
});
```

How is jquery alone able to get the height of the hidden div? Thanks!

Comment: can you please explain what exactly you want

Comment: You're already use JQuery, but why still using `document.getElementById("test")`? Why not using `$('#test');`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery

Comment: It is not a problem I am facing. I just want to understand how jquery is able to get the height.

Comment: why would you think storing the height before hiding the div, would be any tough for jquery??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain JavaScript you can do something like this and it should work:

```
// $("#test").hide();
// alert($("#test").height());

var el = document.getElementById("test");
el.style.position = 'absolute';
el.style.visibility = 'hidden';

alert(el.offsetHeight); // 40
```

jQuery is probably doing the magic for you in some other way. It's not reliable to get dimensions of hidden objects with `display: none`.

**Edit:** Here's the [jQuery code that handles dimensions](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/dimensions.js). You'll have to connect some dots but it doesn't seem very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("test").getBoundingClientRect().height;
    $("#test").hide();
    alert($("#test").height());
    alert(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get height of div using,

```
$('#test1').height();
$('#test2').height();
```

height() function computes height of given element.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get much from the other answers and wanted to know the same thing and found the [relevant lines in the jQuery 3.0.0-pre source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L332).

These properties get temporarily added to the element using [this swap function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/var/swap.js) if `getClientRects()` or `getBoundingClientRect()` don't return anything useful:

```
{ position: "absolute", visibility: "hidden", display: "block" }
```

Then it calls `val = elem.getBoundingClientRect()[ name ];` to get the width (line 127 - 3.0.0-pre).

Answer (score 0):

Notice the difference : http://jsfiddle.net/YJMrE/5/

Jquery hides it, so it knows what the hidden element's height was before hiding.

While javascript simply returns the current height.

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    alert(document.getElementById("test").getBoundingClientRect().height); // 40
    $("#test").hide();    
    alert(document.getElementById("test").getBoundingClientRect().height); // 0
});
```