# Is it possible to determine the height of an element without attaching it first to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, browser

Is it possible to determine the height of an element without attaching it first to the DOM?
I'd like to determine the height ahead of time to pre-calculate absolute positions.

Comment: Position it offscreen and measure it. No one will know or see the element. (position:fixed;top:-9999px);

Comment: you may want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery

Comment: The context into which the element is added to the DOM may have a tremendous impact on the size. Different parts of the page may have different font size rules, different widths, line heights, etc etc. In general, the answer is "no".

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the expensive reflow and repaint process or at least limit the number of times this occurs. How do I do this? If I make all the elements I attach to my DOM hidden and then show them all at the end, would that achieve the desired effect?