# Fadein and Fadeout stopping jquery function from working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

I've put together an example to help explain the issue: http://codepen.io/tathianactn/pen/EaEzRB.

In this example I have a Map and various markers on the map (the blue squares). When you hover over the markers, a tooltip should appear with an image (left) and some text (right).  The image & text div should always be the same height, therefore I am using javascript to determine the tallest div, and assigning that height value to the shorter div.

Initially the tooltip div is marked as "display: none;", then as you hover over a marker it "fadesin" and when you hover off the marker it "fadesout".

I have tested this code step by step, and all was working correctly until I added the fadein / fadeout actions.  Before adding those two actions, the javascript re-sizing worked just fine (you can try removing those two lines to see), however when I added in those fade actions the heights stopped working correctly.

I noticed that if you quickly hover off and then hover back on the same marker, the height re-sizing does take effect.

Any ideas?  I added the fadein after the re-sizing, supposing that all of the re-sizing would get done before the tooltip was exposed, but something is certainly not working correctly.

I would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

```
$('a.map_marker').hover(function(e) {

   //Change tooltip content based on location of marker clicked
   var elementToGet = '.tooltip_html_source.'+$(this).attr('location');
   var newHTML = $(elementToGet).html();
   $('#tooltip_container .tooltip_content').html(newHTML);

   //Get height of text div
   var textHeight = $('#tooltip_container .tooltip_content .text').height();

   //If text div is less than 70px (min height of image div)
   if(textHeight < 70) {

      //Then make the height of the text div = 70px
      $('#tooltip_container .tooltip_content .text').height(70);
   }

   // else if the text div is greater than 70px
   else if(textHeight > 70) {

      //Make the height of the image div = the height of the text div
      $('#tooltip_container .tooltip_content .image').height(textHeight);
   }

   //Once the resizing has been done, fade in the tooltip div
   $('#tooltip_container').fadeIn('slow');

}, function() {

   //On hover off, fade out the tooltip div
   $('#tooltip_container').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that [width & height of invisible elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery) (i.e. elements with `display` CSS property set to `none`) are undefined.

And because your `#tooltip_container` is indeed has `display: none;` style, you can't  get its actual height before you show it in some way on the page e.g. by setting `display` to `block`. But there's a trick: before you start your fading sequence, you can make it effectively invisible - either with `opacity` set to `0`, or by adding `visibility: hidden;` style.

The immediate solution to your problem would be to move `fadeIn` animation up - before you start measuring the element you're fading:

```
// Start fading the element
$('#tooltip_container').fadeIn('slow');

//Get height of text div
var textHeight = $('#tooltip_container .tooltip_content .text').height();

//If text div is less than 70px (min height of image div)
if(textHeight < 70) ...

// Rest of the code follows
```

(Full code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogqrQo)

The reason it works is because `fadeIn` immediately sets `display` to `block`/`inline`/`inline-block`, while setting opacity to `0.0` (and gradually increasing it) - therefore your `#tooltip_container` element gets rendered on the page, and you can get its height.

Comment: Excellent @NikitaBaksalyar!  This worked perfectly with the example code I put together and with the actual project I am working on.  Thanks for providing a solution, and especially for taking the time to explain the "why".  Thanks so much!