# how to obtain an element's width inside backbone render function

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am using backbone. I need to obtain an element's width inside the backbone render function. But unfortunately, that is not possible, because the element has not yet been added to the dom. Is there a way to obtain an element's width inide the backbone render function?

Comment: nope. you need to place it first. its not backbones fault though -- its the dom

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the width without actually inserting the view to DOM, however, you can get the value by inserting it without the user seeing it by giving it negative `z-index`, `opacity:0` etc, something along [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2345813/2333214).

If you really really don't want to insert it in DOM for some reason, then you can make a hidden clone of it and insert that instead to find the dimensions.