# Get the height of an element binded to an onClick event without clicking it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set a height of an element back to its original state but the element is hidden by default (display:none) and is only activated by an on click event.

How do I go about getting the height of the element without actually clicking on the element first?

Right now I'm using this code but it's defining the height as 0 of course, because the element hasn't been displayed yet.

```
var initHeightInner = $('#div').find('.list').height();
```

Comment: share your code ..!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Get height of hidden element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You may set link's opacity to 0 and/or visibility:hidden. Then you'll be able to get it's actual height.
Here is example bellow to show you the difference

```js
console.log('Hidden', document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0].clientHeight)
console.log('Opacity', document.getElementsByClassName('opacity')[0].clientHeight)
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.opacity{
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px;
  top:-9999px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hidden">Hidden</a>
<a href="#" class="opacity">Zero opacity</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is normal because your element is initially defined with a `height` equal to zero. therefore, you must either remove the `height: 0;` property and use only `visibility: hidden` ... but in this case it may affect the animation of this element on click event. so you can try to add a new div (for example with the .list-body class) below your .list element and try to get the height from this element.
like : `var initHeightInner = $('#div').find('.list-body').height()`