# Get width of ul in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to get the width of a `<ul>` which has a dynamic width, in order to set the width for its enclosing `<li>`s to the width of the `<ul>` for IE7.

The `<ul>` is styled `display:block`. Currently jQuery's `.width()` returns `0`. I tried to get the widest `<li>`'s width, because it sets the width for the `<ul>`'s but here, I get `0`, too?

Is there any way (or workaround) to get the width of the `<ul>` or its `<li>`s?

Laura

Comment: Sharing some of your markup, css and javascript would be helpful.

Comment: Is your `<ul>` in a visible parent?

Comment: @jerluc nope. It is a dropdown menu.

Comment: @Laura - have you tried "offsetWidth"? It's a JavaScript.

Comment: @domanokz Yes, I Used jQuery and its width() function, which returned a 0.

Comment: @Laura - I mean not jQuery, try this `document.getElementById("YourElement").offsetWidth` instead of  `$('#YourElement').width()`

Comment: In CSS set `display:block` and `visibility:hidden`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the method "offsetWidth":

```
<ul id="MyElement" style="display:block;visibility:hidden;">
    <li>Hello World!</li>
    <li>Hellow Web!</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById('MyElement').offsetWidth);
</script>
```

It should return an element's dynamic width.

Or if you want jQuery try to add this to your jQuery file (jquery.js)

```
jQuery.fn.offsetWidth = function () {
    return this.offsetWidth;
}
```

If it's set to hidden (seems to be the problem) and still returns 0 as width, try to clone the element (the element you want to get the width from). Set css `position:absolute; left:-200; top -200;visibility:visible;` of your element copy. Get the width of the element copy either jQuery or just JavaScript. Remove the element copy. You should now get the width. The `top` and `left` is set negative so the element copy won't appear on your screen.

Note that this can make your execution a little bit slower.

Comment: Like this: 'jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('div.level-0').children('ul').children('li').each(function(){
  var width = $(this).offsetWidth();
  alert(width);
 });       
});
jQuery.fn.offsetWidth = function () {
      return this.offsetWidth;
  }'  ?

Comment: Hm, no put it on your jquery.js file... Or are you referencing your jQuery from other website? If so, try my suggestions above, I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't like hidden elements: [jQuery - Get Width of Element when Not Visible (Display: None)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472303/jquery-get-width-of-element-when-not-visible-display-none)

Comment: hmmmm...good idea, but there is a div wrapped around the ul's. it is hidden, too, but I get its width, also when it is hidden.

Comment: Do you have any code you can post to further illustrate your situation?

Comment: @laura is it `display:none` or `visibility: hidden` ?

Comment: @James, good point, as jQuery is fine with `visibility: hidden`, just not `display: none` on the parent div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nrf5V/ Shows the difference between `visibility` and `display` in terms of jQuery and `.width()`

Comment: this should be a vote to close as duplicate instead of an answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing your script as a part of $(document).ready() handler? Like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Here.
});
```

Or is it run when the page is loading?
Maybe your script is executed before the width of the `<ul>` is set.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the list items to have bullets? If you don't, this can be solved with CSS only, by applying `display:block` to the `<li>`s.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do dropdowns is to set them to be position: absolute and left: -5000px (instead of display: none). That way you can just set/remove the "left" property when you want to hide/show them, and the dimensions of the element are always available. Since you haven't posted any code/markup, I'm not sure if this suggestion would work in your situation, but I thought I'd throw it out there.

As for answering your question, you should use offsetWidth, and remember to add the padding, border width, and margin values of the element to the offsetWidth too.