# Clever way to predict width

Tags: javascript

I need a way to predict the width of a string if it were to be added inside an element.

The font size is 16px.
My original idea was to do 16px for every character but that ended up being wrong.. Any ideas?

Comment: Still confusing, add more information to your question.

Comment: [This](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/getting-the-width-of-a-hidden-element-with-jquery-using-width/) might help. (Inspired by a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472303/jquery-get-width-of-element-when-not-visible-display-none).)

Comment: its given you add hidden element append all text to it and get its width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the string to the body like so:

```
function get_width_of_string() { 
    var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.position = "absolute";
        div.style.marginLeft = "-99999px";
        div.style.display = "inline-block";
    div.innerHTML =  "this is a  string";

    document.body.appendChild(div);

    var width = div.offsetWidth;
    document.body.removeChild(div);
    return width;
}
```

this should return the width of the string