# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'offset'

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to create an element on the fly and then get the center of said element.  Here is what I have:

```
function drawnode(entity, x, y) {

    var ele = ""
    ele += "<div class='relNode'>";
    ele += "<span>" + entity.name() + "</span>"
    ele += "<div>"

    var node = $(ele).appendTo('#rPaper').get(0);
    var offset = node.offset();
    var width = node.width();
    var height = node.height();

    var centerX = offset.left + width / 2;
    var centerY = offset.top + height / 2;

    node.css("top", centerY + y).css("left", centerX + x);

}
```

This gives the error

> `Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'offset'`

I originally tried it without the `.get(0)` and it gives no errors but the height and width are both 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call `jQuery` function on `DOM` object as get gives you `DOM` object not jQuery object Use `eq()` instead of `get()` to get jQuery object

```
 var node = $(ele).appendTo('#rPaper').eq(0);
```

Comment: I don't think it is required as the `ele` has only one root element

Comment: @ScottBeeson: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/FZNam/. Could it be that `#rPaper` or any other descendant of `node`  is not visible? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Hmm, that probably is the problem.  It's in a tab, but the function is called before that tab is selected.

Comment: @Scott: Then that's your problem.

Comment: Hmm, is there an easy fix or will I have to wait until the tab is visible to draw the nodes?

Comment: @Scott: You could show and hide the element (http://jsfiddle.net/FZNam/2/). But that could lead to flashing content, you'd have to test if it works for you. This might work better for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1472303/218196.

Answer (score 0):

[.get(index)](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns a dom element reference which does not have methods like [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) which are provided by jQuery. so you need to use a jQuery wrapper for the element to use methods like [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)/[.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

```
var node = $(ele).appendTo('#rPaper');
```

Comment: That's what I had originally, but then the height and width are 0.

Comment: @ScottBeeson are you sure that the element `#rPaper` exists in the dom

Comment: Yes.  I can see the new element on the page when it is created.

Comment: @ScottBeeson can you help to recreate the problem.. in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vsjA5/1/) it seems to be working fine

Comment: Yeah, @Felix King just pointed out that the problem is probably caused by the fact that #rPaper is on a tab that isn't initially visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var node = $(ele).appendTo('#rPaper');
 var offset = node.offset();
```

Comment: That's what I had originally, but then the height and width are 0