# Clone Ancestor, and Look for Self's Copy in Cloned Ancestor

Tags: jquery, clone, closest

I'm pretty new to jquery and need some help.

I'm trying to clone a copy of the closest ancestor with class 'hidden' of $el and then look for $el's copy in the clone ancestor($hidden).

```
var $hidden = $el.closest('.hidden'),
    $substitute = $hidden
        .clone()
        .appendTo($hidden.parent());
```

Then I try to find $el's copy in $substitute. I tried this:

```
$substitute.find($el);
```

But it doesn't work..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't. `$el` has nothing to do with a descendant of the cloned element. Apart from that `find` doesn't work that way. Logically you don't query for something that you already have.

Comment: you can try adding a data attribute to `$el` and then doing a `$substitute.find('[your-data-attrib]')` call.

Comment: Thanks @undefined . So is there a way that I can get the selector of $el and modified it and use the modified selector to get the cloned $el? I'm doing this is because I need to find .width() of $el but unfortunately $el is a descendant of a hidden element. Thanks very much!

Comment: This might be relavant  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472303/jquery-get-width-of-element-when-not-visible-display-none

Comment: Thanks @Derek ! Although $el.data("a","b") doesn't work well for my case which I believe it's due to the code base, I used addClass and it works now! Thanks for your inspiration! BTW, how can I vote up your answer?

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer for ya to vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a data attribute to `$el` and then doing a `$substitute.find('[your-data-attrib]')` call

Comment: @Derek.. Oops.. Just realized doesn't have enough reputation.. Sorry man.